# What is the git command to push an existing project to an existing git repository branch?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-push

I'm quite new to git and got confused with git commands. I have a project and I need to push it to an existing git repository branch. It is not the master branch but another separate branch that I have asked to work on.
Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After you've created a commit, push it to a branch via:

`git push <remote name> <branch name>`

If you haven't added the remote repository to your current environment yet, add it via:

`git remote add <remote name> <URL>`

Where `<remote name>` is a name you choose (conventionally "origin", referring to the remote repository as the origin of all source), and the `<URL>` is the URL of the remote repository that you were given.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try it. I really appreciate your help!